# What was Bob's job when he was originally Mr. Incredible?

Tags: pixar, the-incredibles

After superheroes are forced to retire, Bob has to get a job in insurance, which he clearly hates.

During his original superhero days, something was paying for lifestyle, which included an incredibly advanced supercar. He makes some endorsements, but there isn't any indication they'd be enough to support himself, at least at the beginning of his superhero career. I don't think there's any mention of the government supporting him, so how did he make money?

Comment: I thought it so that they had NO other job than being superheroes (as after the court it was mentioned they now live NORMAL lives).

Comment: @Thomas true, but Elastigirl also says something about "not going to the groceries dressed as Elastigirl", so that money has to come from somewhere, I guess. (In addition to Bob's car etc)

Comment: @Jenayah I thought that the government pays them tbh. But thinking it over there was a phrase "now their secret identities stay their only ones". So I guess.....they really had jobs prolly!

Comment: The govt likely paid them for their services, but they still would have needed secret identities to go to stores to spend that money.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Not necessarily. If the government could find the money to pay them I am sure they could find a lackey to run to whole foods and pick up some groceries and leave them in a drop box next to the house... The valid part of this question is "What did they do before becoming their superhero namesakes?" Honestly to answer that though we would still need to know if they were born naturally or made in a lab, which I don't think we honestly know either...

Comment: @Odin1806 Edna has stated that supers are born with powers that manifest in early childhood. But yeah, we don't know if the govt created the first supers in a lab, or if they were born to ordinary parents naturally.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - There was mention in the deleted scenes that Supers are forbidden by law to breed with each other

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a considerable number of money-spinners on his [wall of fame](https://cdn1.theyoungfolks.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/12123923/incredibles-disneyscreencaps.com-3936.jpg)

- The Mr Incredible Cadets
- An album of covered songs ("*Mr Incredible Sings...*") which, according to the *[Incredibles Essential Guide](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2125677.The_Incredibles_Essential_Guide)* went '*quadruple platinum*'
- Merchandise aplenty (lunchboxes, patches, pez dispenser, branded Rock 'Em Sock 'Em Robots game, etc).
- An action figure and various toy cars
- A branded cereal ("*Incredible Pops!*")
- Mr Incredible [Official Fan Club](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwQAm.png)
- A Mr Incredible branded comic book (*"The Most Incredible Comic on Earth!*")
- Endorsements ("*[Bonhomie - It's the car Mr Incredible would drive...](http://deadshirt.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/incredibles-disneyscreencaps.com-3647.jpg)*")

[image]

We learn from the commentary track to "[The Adventures of Mr Incredible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1R44MvXeEQw)" that he's protective of his intellectual property (if not especially worried about quality) which strongly implies that he's getting a cut of any sales that are made with his likeness.

---

Note that Mr Incredible's super-car (the Incredibile) was supplied by the [National Supers Agency](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d73WtJlko9E). There's also a magazine feature about the Incredi**boat** and he's, presumably, receiving other payments and equipment from them.

[image]

Comment: At first glance thought he was protective of his bile

Comment: “Won legendary eating contest”. He truly is Mr. Incredible! That also explains why his stomach gets stuck going though that chute.

Comment: @Thunderforge "a liter of mayonnaise" - gross.

Comment: @RogueJedi - I guess it depends on your appetite. Last time I had fries, I consumed 4oz of mayo. Mr Incredible clear eats more in a single sitting than 10 men, so a litre of mayonnaise isn't that big of a deal

Comment: @valorum But based on that list, he either ate the mayonnaise with various dessert products, or consumed it raw.

Comment: @RogueJedi - Eating it out of the jar isn't cool, I'll agree with you on that.

Comment: mayonnaise is good on the keto diet - but with those pies, it's clear that isn't for him ...

Comment: @davidbak - He was in pretty good shape while he was doing his superhero stuff.